# How to fetch number of customers or clients who have made payment within a particular period

Tags: sql

I have two tables studentstable and payment
I want to get the number of students in a particular class who have made payment in a particular term
This is my code

```
SELECT classform, student_id, COUNT(student_id) as countreport_class
FROM studentstable s JOIN
     (SELECT studentid
      FROM payment
      WHERE term= ? AND acayear=?
     ) AS pa
     ON pa.studentid = s.student_id AND s.classform=? 
GROUP BY s.student_id
```

but the outcome is wrong. It rather shows the number of times a student has made payment...
I need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm expecting something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as countreport_class
FROM studentstable s JOIN
     payment p
     ON p.studentid = s.student_id AND
        p.term = ? AND p.acayear = ?
WHERE s.classform = ? ;
```

If you want the query to return a single number, why are you returning so many columns in the `select`?

The above counts the number of *payments*.  If you want the number of students with a payment, then use `exists`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as countreport_class
FROM studentstable s 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM payment p
              WHERE p.studentid = s.student_id AND
                    p.term = ? AND p.acayear = ?
             ) AND
      s.classform = ? ;
```

Comment: I wanted to asked question about the first code but it's okay..  I haven't tried tho. But the second explanation is that I wanted, I'll try that one and let you know the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: Gordon Linoff I think it's working thanks because I have run it and  it's working fine, I'll test on more records. Please before I mark as answered. Please help me how to get the total amount of payment for the students in a class.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
SELECT distinct studentid
FROM payment
WHERE term = ? AND acayear = ?
```

returns all the students who have made at least 1 payment at this term. 
So if you join the students table to this query and apply the condition of the particular class you will have what you need:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as countreport_class
FROM studentstable s INNER JOIN (
  SELECT distinct studentid
  FROM payment
  WHERE term = ? AND acayear = ?
) AS pa ON pa.studentid = s.studentid 
WHERE s.classform = ?
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7n4gH9DfKj1zb3BzE7AGfu/0)

Comment: See the demo in my edited answer and check why *it did not work for you*.

Comment: You have edited the answer you provided previously. 
This was your answer <code>SELECT s.classform, COUNT(s.student_id) as countreport_class
FROM studentstable s JOIN (
  SELECT distinct studentid
  FROM payment
  WHERE term = ? AND acayear = ?
) AS pa ON pa.studentid = s.student_id 
WHERE s.classform = ?  </code>Butt the first answer worked. So I'm cool. Thanks for your concern.